# From an array of objects, How to get an object's valueB if that object's valueA matches a variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

Lets say you have an array of objects.

```
let dogs = [
  { 
    colour: "blue",
    breed: "poodle"
  },
  { 
    colour: "yellow",
    breed: "poodle"
  },
  { 
    colour: "red",
    breed: "laborator"
  }
];
```

**How do you get the colour when matching by breed?**

I have tried:

```
let myFavouriteColour = dogs.find(dog => {
   if (dog.breed === "laborator") return dog.colour
});
```

This returns me an object that matches the above condition; I only want it to return the value in the `colour` property.

Comment: I don't think "laborator" is a dog breed though. You probably meant "labrador".

Comment: It's what you get when you a cross a "lab" and an "elevator"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`Array.find()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is an inbuilt function in JavaScript which is used to get the object (or value if it's an array of values) of the ***first element*** in the array that satisfies the provided condition. You can access the property on the returned result.

```js
let dogs = [
  { 
    colour: "blue",
    breed: "poodle"
  },
  { 
    colour: "yellow",
    breed: "poodle"
  },
  { 
    colour: "red",
    breed: "laborator"
  }
];

let myFavouriteColour = dogs.find(dog => dog.breed === "laborator").colour;
console.log(myFavouriteColour);
```

Comment: I've misunderstood what array.find() returns; I understood it to return a value, not an object.

Answer (score 2):

Once you `.find` a match, return `true` (or just return an equality test), then access the property of the matched object outside the `.find`:

```js
let dogs = [
  { 
    colour: "blue",
    breed: "poodle"
  },
  { 
    colour: "yellow",
    breed: "poodle"
  },
  { 
    colour: "red",
    breed: "laborator"
  }
];

const laborator = dogs.find(dog => dog.breed === "laborator");
if (laborator) {
  const myFavouriteColour = laborator.colour;
  console.log(myFavouriteColour);
}
```